# Serve files from `.well-known` folder in a React app

Tags: reactjs

I have a React single-page app that routes anything to the same page. I don't have a react-router installed or any `routes.ts` file. The app is deployed to an S3 bucket.

However, I need to serve two files from the `.well-known` folder inside the app. Currently attempts to access those files are also redirected to the main page of the React app.

How do I serve two files from a folder while redirecting any other requests to the React app?

Comment: You say you _aren't_ using react-router, but you've got it as a question tag. Also, if you don't have it then what's your current redirecting method?

Comment: @Jayce444 I wish I knew how it works now; I checked `package-lock.json` and react-router is not there.

Answer (score 16):

The solution is:

1. Place the files you want to be served into the `public/` folder (not into `src/`).
2. Add references to those files into `index.html` in the `public/` folder, using a `%PUBLIC_URL%` as the path:

```html
<link rel="assetlinks.json file" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/.well-known/assetlinks.json" />
<link rel="apple-app-site-association file" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/.well-known/apple-app-site-association" />
```

After that, the React app will start serving the static files from the expected URL.

Comment: it is not serving me the file.. but it can serve styles.css

Comment: this way is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using create-react-app or a similar mechanism, you should be able to simply add the files to public/.well-known as this folder is not processed by webpack and files there should be copied directly to the build root and served statically as expected.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!